# What are the abelianizations of $\Gamma_0(N)?$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

It is well-known that the abelianization of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the cyclic group $\{T^n\mid n=0,...,11\},$ where
$$
T=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I would like to know the abelianizations of $\Gamma_0(N),$ especially for small $N$. Does anyone know them?

Comment: They may be known in general, but for small $N$ you can calculate them on a computer (using GAP for example) using the presentation $\langle x,y \mid x^4=1, x^2=y^3 \rangle$ of ${\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Z})$.

Comment: The abelianization of $Γ_0(N)$ is essentially due to Lee and Szczarba, published in Inventiones Math. 1976.

Comment: I sometimes use Mathematica but have never used GAP. As I hear that GAP is useful for group theory, I will learn GAP and try to calculate the abelianization.

Comment: I found the paper of Lee and Szczarba. I will read it.